# Line length exceeded when forwarding email

Tags: email

I'm using Thunderbird.
Sometimes, when forwarding a message, as an attachment, I get an error "An error occurred while sending mail.
The mail server responded:

```
Line length exceeded. See RFC 2821 #4.5.3.1.. Please check the message and try again."
```

**2 questions**.
 If I can't forward the message, how did it get sent to me in the first place? Is there some way, an add-on or something, that I can clean up the message so that I can forward it?

Comment: This is not a programming question. There are websites on the Stack Exchange network those can be more suitable for this question. Like https://superuser.com/ if it's a question about Thunderbird mail client or https://serverfault.com/ if this question is about the mail server.

Comment: If the message arrives within your internal network, mail server protections etc are probably more lenient than what you'll find on public-facing mail servers. Anyway, the problem is probably that somebody wrote a script which creates email messages with very long lines. Anything with a `Content-type:` other than `binary` has restrictions on line length; the script needs to insert line breaks somehow. `base64` and `quoted-printable` are both good encodings to use to overcome this; tell your programmer to use them.